# Pythonic way to skip items in an iterable?

Tags: python, iterator, idioms

Say I have an iterable and want to skip elements as long as the elements match a particular predicate. *I want to affect the current iterator, not return a new one*.

I could simply do this:

```
# untested, just for explanation

e = next(iterable)
while True:
    if something(e):
        e = next(iterable)
    else:
         break
```

But is there a built-in function for this, or some common idiom?

Answer (score 3):

This is the basic use-case of [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
e = next(iterable)
while something(e):
  e = next(iterable)
```

Also, why "I want to affect the current iterator, not return a new one."? I can't think of a scenario when you would need that. If you allow for a new iterator to wrap the current one, `itertools.dropwhile` that wim suggests is much more Pythonic (and readable).

Answer (score 0):

Your example just plain stops after the first false result, so this does the same:

```
>>> it = iter(range(100000)) # just constructing _an_ iterator
>>> next(itertools.filterfalse(lambda i: i != 12, it))
12
```

I'm not clear on what - exactly - "I want to affect the current iterator, not return a new one" means, but do note that `it` itself has advanced:

```
>>> next(it)
13
```